# PHP Regex get the last "/" or "\"

Tags: php, regex

I have a set of data following 


C://path/path/path/path/xyz.jpg

or

C://path/path/path/path\xyz.jpg

using `preg_replace('/(^.*\/)|(^.*\\)/gi', '', $path);`

I am able to run it in online tester (eg http://www.regextester.com/)
but it won't work in my PHP code, please help.

Comment: What would be the expected output?

Comment: it will only leave the filename.jpg such as `xyz.jpg`

Comment: What doesn't work, did you get some error message or ... ?

Comment: base name work like a charm... ms window -_- a mess up mixing forward & backward slash...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the g modifier and double escape the `\`:

```
$file = preg_replace('/(^.*\/)|(^.*\\\\)/', '', $path);
```

or

```
$file = preg_replace('~^.*[/\\\\]~', '', $path);
```

Comment: so... that's how you escape it @_@. Thanks~